# C# Manage SubForm from MainForm

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a main form(fGraph) and a sub form (fScheduller). In the main form
I need to send a value to the sub-form and call refresh void in the sub form,
but I receive an exception: **System.NullReferenceException**: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

How can I manage the sub form from the main form?

the main form:

```
namespace WorkSpace
{
    public partial class fGraph : DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm
    {
        private void fGraph_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            _fScheduller = new SpecialForms.fScheduller();
            _fScheduller.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            _fScheduller.TopLevel = false;
            _fScheduller.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            _fScheduller.Show();
            _fScheduller.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            layoutControlGroupSchedule.Controls.Add(_fScheduller);
        }
        private void reload()
        {
            _fScheduller.fillSceduleControls(Convert.ToInt64(current["SCHEDULE_ID"]));
            // EXCEPTION : System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
        }
    }
}
```

the sub form:

```
namespace SpecialForms
{
    public partial class fScheduller : Form
    {
        public fScheduller()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void fillSceduleControls(long sched_id)
        {

            leScFreqType.EditValue = GetFreqType(sched_id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when is `reload()` being called?

Comment: 2 possible mistakes: first- the `reload()` method is beeing called before `fGraph_Load` so `_fScheduller` is obviously `null` or second - the `current` collection/array is null

Comment: I have gridcontrol binded to dataset
When Current value in dataset changed I need to reroad values in controls of subform

Comment: just set a breakpoint at `reload` and you will instantly see if and why it's `null`. this question was not necessary..

Comment: Yes you are right
I call reload() before creating subform
many thanks.!!!